# count NULL for all columns in hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table with 300 columns (mixed datatype), I want to check what percentage of records have NULL values in all the columns. Can it be done simply.

```
col: 1     2     3     4     ...... 300
     A     4     null  78    ...... 300 columns
     B     null  70    90    ...... 300 columns
     c     4     null  78    ...... 300 columns
     g     null  72    90    ...... 300 columns
     t     4     98    null  ...... 300 columns
     null  null  70    90    ...... 300 columns
     A     4     null  78    ...... 300 columns
     B     null  70    90    ...... 300 columns
```

Result should be:

```
col 1: 12.5% (1/8 is null)
col 2: 50%
col 3: 37.5
col 4: 12.5%
.
.
col 300: x%
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the *best* way to do this, but here is how I would solve this problem (I'll provide an example for 10 columns). In `python` run,

```
>>> for i in xrange(1,11):
...    print "col{0}".format(i)
...
```

It will print

```
col1
col2
 .
 .
 .
col10
```

Copy and past this to [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  Highlight the columns (CTRL+A) and type **CTRL+SHIFT+L** and then hit the LEFT arrow.  Now you should have 10 (or in your case 300) cursors. Type

```
, sum(case when
```

then skip over the `col`

```
is null then 1 else 0) / count(*)
```

[image]

it should look like that.   Then put a `select` statement on top and a `from` below.

Comment: If you you really want to use this method, why not enter the entire query in your print statement and skip the sublime part? `print("sum(case when col{} is null then 1 else 0) / count(*),".format(i))`

Comment: try Sublime text + plugin(Text Pastry)

Comment: The `end` is missing at the end :) The query would therefore be `sum(case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should be as simple as calculating the ratio of the `null` count to the total count.

Something like this:

```
col1 AS (select count(col1) from table where col1 IS NULL / total_count) * 100.
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I need something that does it for all the columns, this query will do for one column only. I dont want to run this query 300 times if there are 300 columns

Comment: I too wonder how to do this for a set of columns and not one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`Count(*)` will count all the rows.
`Count(column1)` will count all the rows that are not null for the column.

Combine these to form the query:

```
select ((tot_count - a.non_null1)/tot_count)*100 as pcnt_null_col1 
     , ((tot_count - a.non_null2)/tot_count)*100 as pcnt_null_col2
from
(select count(column1) as non_null1, count(column1) as non_null2 from my_table) a
Left outer join
(select count(*) as tot_cnt from my_table) b
on (1=1)
```

There are other ways to do this but this way you only have to scan the table once to get the total count.

Another variation:

```
select (1 - a.non_null1/tot_count)*100 as pcnt_null_col1 
     , (1 - a.non_null2/tot_count)*100 as pcnt_null_col2
from
(select count(column1) as non_null1, count(column1) as non_null2 from my_table) a
Left outer join
(select count(*) as tot_cnt from my_table) b 
 on (1=1)
```

EDIT:  To clarify... if you don't join the total count then for each count(*) in the query hive will perform an additional scan.  If you join the total then hive will only scan once.  This is why I did it with a join.

Gobrewers14 is building out the code using sublime text and I think his method is good idea for that pruprose.  Good luck!

Comment: I did not get this answer. I need something that does it for all the 300 columns in the table. I do not want to run a query 300 times to get % of 300 columns

Comment: You don't need 300 queries.  You can see how it is done with two columns.  You can extend it to as many as needed.  The problem is that you likely don't want to write all that code.  I don't blame you for that.  You could come up with a creative solution to have the code generated but there is no macro facility as of yet.  Otherwise you may want to consider writing a custom UDF.  Good luck.

Comment: No need for a JOIN by the way: `select
   concat('Rows: ', cast(count(*) as String))
 , concat('Nulls in AAA:', cast(cast((1.0 -count(AAA)/count(*)) *100.0 as decimal(4,1)) as string), '%')
 , concat('Nulls in BBB:', cast(cast((1.0 -count(BBB)/count(*)) *100.0 as decimal(4,1)) as string), '%')
from BlahBlah` will return a single row with as many columns as required (1+2 in this case) => `Rows: 13  Nulls in AAA:0%  Nulls in BBB:53.8%`

Comment: If don't join it will scan the table once for each instance of count(*).  This is the only reason I wrote it that way.  You will lose a lot of efficiency if you don't join.

Answer (score -1):

You can set up the query string in R or Python (R solution provided) to dynamically include all columns.

Depending on the infra you're using, you can connect directly to your database using the RODBC or DBI packages in R.

```
columns <- c("a", "b", "c") # This should be a vector resulting from a "SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable" query.
table_name <- "mytable"
paste("SELECT ",
       paste(sprintf("(COUNT(*) - COUNT(%s))/COUNT(*) AS %s_nulls, ", columns[1:(length(columns)-1)], columns[1:(length(columns)-1)]), collapse = ""),
       sprintf("(COUNT(*) - COUNT(%s))/COUNT(*) AS %s_nulls ", columns[length(columns)],  columns[length(columns)]), 
       sprintf("FROM  myschema.%s;", table_name), sep = "")
```

This will produce a string containing

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) - COUNT(a))/COUNT(*) AS a_nulls, (COUNT(*) - COUNT(b))/COUNT(*) AS b_nulls, (COUNT(*) - COUNT(c))/COUNT(*) AS c_nulls FROM  myschema.mytable
```

This solution will scale to as many columns as you like, and will adjust for different numbers of columns if you want to run this on multiple tables.